# Runtime.exec() returning null

Tags: java, cmd, process, tasklist

I have seen similiar questions on this site, but none of them seem to address/solve my problem, so I figured there is something specifically wrong with my program. I am trying to execute a very simple command, which is to take a string of a process name from a textfield input and concatenate it to a command to return and print the title of the window. This is my code:

```
        String line;
        Process p = null;
        try
        {
            String command = "tasklist /v /fo list /fi \"imagename eq  " + tf.getText().trim() + "*\"| find /i  \"window title:\"\n";
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader input =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println(command);
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.trim();
                System.out.println(line);

            }
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, the line returned by the InputStream is always null, even though if I put the command used in .exec() into cmd (I printed it so I know they are the exact same), it works properly, albeit after a 5 seconds or so of delay. I tried it with 2 different process names and they both worked on cmd, but not in this java program. This is the output of the above code, in case that helps (the blank line is presumably from the \n at the end of the command string):

```
tasklist /v /fo list /fi "imagename eq  notepad*"| find /i  "window title:"

done
```

I tried adding p.waitFor() after calling .exec(), but that didn't seem to change anything. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps you're reading the wrong stream. The command might be printing to stderr, not stdout. It is generally a good idea to merge them, for which you need to use `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Consider using [ProcessHandle.allProcesses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#allProcesses()) instead of Runtime.exec.  For example, `ProcessHandle.allProcesses().filter(p -> p.info().command().filter(cmd -> cmd.equals(targetName)).isPresent())`.

Comment: I recommend also to use `ProcessHandle.allProcesses()`. What is wrong with currently used code is the missing `"` at end of last argument for `tasklist` and the fact that just the file name `tasklist` is used instead of full qualified file name `C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe` whereby `C:\Windows` is just the default and can be different on a computer. [System.getenv("SystemRoot")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) can be used to get the Windows folder path and concatenate the returned string on not being null with `"\\System32\\tasklist.exe"`.

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which is used on Windows by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to run an executable. This function does not search for a file with name `tasklist` in current directory and next in all directories of environment variable `PATH` having one of the file extensions of environment variable `PATHEXT` as `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe`, `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe` do. That is written explicitly in the doc.

Comment: The full qualified file name of `find` is `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe`. The execution of the command line `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /V /FO LIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq  notepad*"| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I  "window title:"` would require the execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` because of CMD redirection operator `|` with the command line `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /V /FO LIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq  notepad*"| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I  "window title:""`

Comment: But it would be better to use just `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /V /FO LIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq  notepad*"` on not using `ProcessHandle.allProcesses()` for some reasons and filter the captured output with Java code to reduce the dependencies on other executables and their configuration to a minimum. Yes, `cmd.exe` execution can be configured and is much too often misconfigured causing lots of troubles with applications running (most often unnecessary) the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` until the misconfiguration is fixed by the user with help of experts.

Comment: So `Runtime.exec()` is ***not*** 'returning null', but reading the process's standard output as lines is returning null. Which only means it produced nothing on its standard output. Be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with launching the command. Firstly you are ignoring error stream so don't see the actual problem.

Replace `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` with `ProcessBuilder` to get access to error message:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream();
p = pb.start();
```

This will tell you that `tasklist` is not a process. Normally using full pathname would fix this type of error, but as you are using pipe the whole command must sent to to CMD.EXE to interpret pipe components correctly. Run CMD.EXE then your piped command:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
pb.redirectErrorStream();
p = pb.start();
```

Prints:

```
tasklist /v /fo list /fi "imagename eq  notepad*"| find /i  "window title:"

Window Title: Notepad++
done
```

It's also easier to read STDOUT with simple transfer:

```
try(var stdout = p.getInputStream()) {
    stdout.transferTo(System.out);  // or where-ever
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I knew I had to use ProcessBuilder in some way, but was unfamiliar and a bit confused.